# How do I change the Solr behavior for passing 2 word queries? (under plone)

Tags: solr, plone

I am using the Collective Solr 4.1.0 Search on our Plone 4.2.6 system. So far so good, there is one problem I was not yet able to fix.
When the user enters 'Michael Smith' in the search field, the query get's passed to Solr as in the following example:

```
+((givenName:(Michael) (Smith)) OR (surname:(Michael) (Smith)))
```

This way both fields givenName and surname are only searched for Michael. I'd rather have it this way:

```
+((givenName:(Michael OR Smith)) OR (surname:(Michael OR Smith)))
```

Since I fetch the user entry with {value} or {base_value}, which automatically makes it `(Michael) (Smith)`, I don't know how to tell Solr to put an 'OR' inbetween or how to change the user query anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsing through another forum I just found the solution for my particular problem: parentheses.
In the backend, when I enter `+(surname:{base_value})`, that is replaced by `+(surname:(Michael) (Smith))`. Smith is then used for the default field.

The simple solution here is to put {base_value} in parentheses. `+surname:({base_value})` then becomes `+surname:((Michael) (Smith))` and is automatically handled like having an 'OR' inbetween.